# setTypeface textview from ListMenuAdapter

Tags: android, fonts, android-listview

I have a class with an `ListMenuAdapter` inside it :

```
ListMenuAdapter adapter = new ListMenuAdapter(this, R.layout.listmenu_item, listMenuData);
```

The problem is : **i cant access textview from `R.layout.listmenu_item`. I need to access it because i want to change its Typeface.**

This is the full code :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    ListMenu listMenuData[] = new ListMenu[]
    {
        new ListMenu(R.drawable.final_test, "Hello World ^_^", getHighScore(1)),
        new ListMenu(R.drawable.introduction, "Introduction", getHighScore(1)),
        new ListMenu(R.drawable.input_output, "Input - Output", getHighScore(2))
    };


    ListMenuAdapter adapter = new ListMenuAdapter(this, R.layout.listmenu_item, listMenuData);

    listMenu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listMenu);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listmenu_header, null);
    //I TRIED THIS FOR ACCESSING THE TEXTVIEW, BUT NO LUCK
    View titles = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listmenu_item, null);

    Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Androgyne_TB.otf");

    //WORKING
    txtHeader = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
    //NOT WORKING
    txtTitle = (TextView) titles.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    //WORKING    
    txtHeader.setTypeface(customFont);
    //NOT WORKING
    txtTitle.setTypeface(customFont);

    listMenu.addHeaderView(header);

    listMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
    listMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

I have tried to inflate the `R.layout.listmenu_item` for accessing the Textview :

```
View titles = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listmenu_item, null);
```

But its still not working (please see the full code above) :D

**Edited :**

This the the `ListMenuAdapter` `GetView` method :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    MenuHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new MenuHolder();
        holder.imgMenuIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgMenuIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        //holder.txtHighScore = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtHighScore);

        //holder.txtHighScore.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.rtbHighScore = (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.rtbHighScore);
        //holder.rtbHighScore.setNumStars(5);
        //holder.rtbHighScore.setEnabled(false);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else holder = (MenuHolder)row.getTag();

    ListMenu menu = listmenu[position];
    holder.imgMenuIcon.setImageResource(menu.icon);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(menu.title);
    //holder.txtHighScore.setText("High Score : "  + menu.highscore);
    holder.rtbHighScore.setRating(menu.highscore/20);
    return row;
}
```

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: please submit your exceptions if you have any, or explain what does not working mean

Comment: Does your adapter have a getView method? or can you post the code of the adapter?

Comment: Thanks :D
The font is not changing(but the header does, please see my edited full code). Theres no exception at all :D

Comment: @user1281750 yes i have, sorry i forgot to post it :D
Please see my editied question. Thanks :D

Comment: @BlazeTama in your getView() method set the typeface of the texttitle in there under the line holder.txtTitle.setText(menu.title);

Comment: @Saksak Please see my below comment. The problem is i cant create a Typeface object in the getView method :D
Thanks :D

Comment: @BlazeTama check my answer below hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment I left on your question, you can set the typeFace for the title textview in `getView()` method under the line `holder.txtTitle.setText(menu.title);` like following :

to get the typeface instance form Assets, you need to pass Context parameter to your adapter - which i think you already do that- and then use that instance to create the typeface as you did in your `onCreate()` or check edit below :

**Edit**

`Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"Androgyne_TB.otf")`;

then you can set the typeFace as below :

`holder.txtTitle.setTypeFace(customFont);`

Comment: Thanks :D its working now :D
I will edit your answer a little bit to make a clearer answer, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the textview in the getView method of your Adapter.

> holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

After this you can set the typeface

Comment: Do you mean that we set the Typefface in the getView method?the problem is getAssests() cant be used in my adapter class (i think because it dont extends Activity) :D
Thanks :D

Comment: This is the code that not working : Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Androgyne_TB.otf");

Answer (score 1):

```
holder.txtTitle.setText(menu.title);
```

after this in getview try

```
holder.txtTitle.setTypeFace(face);
```

Comment: i cant create the Typeface in the getView() method. The problem is getAssests() cant be used in my adapter class (i think because it dont extends Activity) :D
Thanks

Comment: This is the code that not working : Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "Androgyne_TB.otf");